# Why is the Compositor not showing any nodes?

Tags: rendering, node-editor, compositing-nodes

After rendering a design in blender 2.82 I tried to improve the designs with the nodes but the Composting tab is blank with just the grid showing and no rendering info/nodes

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably accidentally deleted all the nodes.

Simply add a composite node with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > Output > Composite.

If you want to feed it the render from your scene, add a Render Layers node:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > Input > Render Layers

Comment: It Worked, Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome. if your problem is solved, please validate the answer by clicking on the grey check mark ✓ on the left.

Comment: Hi after doing that my renders are coming up blank, please do you know what might be wrong ?

Comment: I would need to see a screenshot of your compositor. Post a link to it in a comment here.

Answer (score 0):

In tool bar search for a tick-box *Use Nodes* (at least for 2.83)

[image: example]

Comment: You can see in his screenshot that "Use Nodes" is enabled.